# How to insert data into another table when the condition is met with trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have these 4 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.person
(
    personId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    firstName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    lastName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pkPerson PRIMARY KEY (personId),
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.personRegistration  
(
    person_registrationId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
    personId INT,                                   
    firstName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,                
    lastName NVARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    confirmed NCHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL,                 

    CONSTRAINT pkpersonRegistration PRIMARY KEY (person_registrationId),
    CONSTRAINT fkpersonRegistration FOREIGN KEY (personId) REFERENCES dbo.person (personId)
    CONSTRAINT personConfirmed CHECK (confirmed IN ('Y', 'N'))
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.person_organizationalUnit
(
    personId INT NOT NULL,
    organizationalUnitId INT NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT pkorganizationalUnit PRIMARY KEY (personId, organizationalUnitId),
    CONSTRAINT fkperson FOREIGN KEY (personId) REFERENCES dbo.person (personId),
    CONSTRAINT fkorganizationalUnit FOREIGN KEY (organizationalUnitId) REFERENCES dbo.organizatinalUnit(unicOrgUnitId),
);

CREATE TABLE dbo.organizatinalUnit
(
    organizationalUnitId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    organizationalUnitName NVARCHAR(130) NOT NULL, 

    CONSTRAINT pkorganizationalUnit PRIMARY KEY (organizationalUnitId)
);
```

I need to create a trigger  which will do that when I add new person in table `personRegistration` (his `personId` is set to NULL, and initial value for confirmed is `'N'`) and when I update `personRegistration` and set confirmed to `'Y'`, that person is going to be inserted into table `person` (value for `personId` is generated because the `personId` is an identity column) and the confirmed is going to change it's value to `'Y'` and is going to be inserted in table `person_organizationalUnit`. I have written the trigger but the problem is when I update the `personRegistration` for more than one person my data double with each update.

```
CREATE TRIGGER personConfirmed
ON dbo.personRegistration
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    INSERT INTO dbo.person (firstName, lastName) 
        SELECT 
            firstName, lastName
        FROM 
            dbo.personRegistration

    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @idPerson int

    SELECT @idPerson = personId 
    FROM dbo.person

    INSERT INTO dbo.person_organizationalUnit (personId, organizationalUnitId)
        SELECT @idPerson, I.organizationalUnitId
        FROM Inserted AS I
        JOIN dbo.person p ON p.personId = @idPerson
        WHERE confirmed  = 'Y';
END
```

Data for insert:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.personRegistration (personId, firstName, lastName, confirmed)
VALUES (NULL, 'John', 'Smith', 'N');
```

Data for update:

```
UPDATE dbo.personRegistration
SET confirmed = 'Y'
WHERE personRegistrationId = 1;
```

Comment: Where did your _data double with each update_ (what table)? I think you may need a `WHERE` clause on your first person `INSERT`, I also think you may want to check for the `Y` update flag before you make an insert into the person table as you mentioned.

Comment: The *first* thing your trigger does is inserts ***all*** the data in `person` into `personRegistration`; is that intended? Can `person` only ever contain 1 row? If not, what do you think `SELECT @idPerson = personId FROM dbo.person` will do?

Comment: I'm confused about the insert into `person_organizationalUnit`, where does it get its data from? Where does `organizationalUnitId` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server triggers works with sets not single register i did some small changes in your trigger

```
create TRIGGER dbo.usp_PersonConfirmed ON dbo.personRegistration
AFTER UPDATE 
AS
  BEGIN

   -- create person if not exists
   INSERT INTO dbo.person (firstName, lastName) 
   SELECT firstName, lastName
   FROM dbo.personRegistration p
   where not exists(select * from dbo.Person where firstName = p.firstName 
    and lastName = p.lastName)


   -- create orgonization unit if person dont exist and confirmed is Y
   INSERT INTO dbo.person_organizationalUnit (personId, organizationalUnitId)
   SELECT i.personId, I.organizationalUnitId
   FROM Inserted AS I
   where not exists(select * from dbo.person_organizationalUnit where 
      personId = i.personId)
      and confirmed  = 'Y';

   -- update orgonization unit if person exist and confirmed is Y
   update pou set organizationalUnitId = I.organizationalUnitId
   from dbo.person_organizationalUnit pou
     inner join Inserted AS I on i.personID = pou.personId
   where  i.confirmed  = 'Y';
END
```

Comment: Your solution works for me, thank you very much for your help and for taking the time to solve my problem.

Comment: I try to return personId back to table personRegistration because I now know which Id John Smith have, and I tried to use part of your code but I get an error that I can't insert the NULL value  into column firsName :     INSERT INTO dbo.personRegistration (personId)
 SELECT@idPerson
    FROM Inserted AS I
 WHERE not exists(SELECT @idPerson FROM dbo.person where
 @idPerson=i.personId);                                              
                                                                                       
 Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: if you want do something like that you should use "instead of"  trigger because if you insert in your personRegistration while you are in trigger you could created recursive calls

Answer (score 1):

Your trigger has a fatal flaw: it does not deeal properly with multiple rows. It is also not using the `inserted` table in the first `INSERT`, and instead selecting from the whole original table.

So you need to `OUTPUT` the identity column from the first insert in order to use it in the second.

Because you don't have the identity column yet, you need to join onto `firstName` and `lastName`, which I need not say isn't a very good primary key

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER personConfirmed
ON dbo.personRegistration
AFTER UPDATE 
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF NOT UPDATE(confirmed) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;  --early bailout

DECLARE @ids TABLE (personId int PRIMARY KEY, firstName nvarchar(100), lastName nvarchar(100));

INSERT INTO dbo.person (firstName, lastName)
OUTPUT inserted.personId, inserted.firstName, inserted.lastName 
SELECT 
    i.firstName,
    i.lastName
FROM 
    inserted i
WHERE i.confirmed  = 'Y';

INSERT INTO dbo.person_organizationalUnit (personId, organizationalUnitId)
SELECT ids.personId, i.organizationalUnitId
FROM inserted AS i
JOIN @ids ids ON i.firstName = ids.firstName AND i.lastName = ids.lastName;
```

Ideally, you have some kind of unique primary key on `personRegistration`. then your trigger would look like this:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER TRIGGER personConfirmed
ON dbo.personRegistration
AFTER UPDATE 
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

IF NOT UPDATE(confirmed) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted)
    RETURN;  --early bailout

DECLARE @ids TABLE (personId int PRIMARY KEY, registrationId int);

MERGE dbo.person p
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM inserted i
    WHERE i.confirmed  = 'Y'
) i
  ON 1 = 0    -- never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (firstName, lastName)
  VALUES (i.firstName, i.lastName)
OUTPUT inserted.personId, i.organizationalUnitId
INTO @ids (personId, organizationalUnitId)
;

INSERT INTO dbo.person_organizationalUnit (personId, organizationalUnitId)
SELECT ids.personId, i.organizationalUnitId
FROM @ids ids;
```

We need that funny `MERGE` because we want to `OUTPUT` columns that we are not inserting. [You can only do this using `MERGE`.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/191257/220697)

Comment: I see, thank you very much for clarification what I was doing wrong and what I have to watch out for in the future.. Arigato sai mas.